# How can I translate 打った人は誰ですか?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentence.

> 打った人は誰ですか。

How can I translate it in English? I don't know who gets hit or who hits.

Do I need to add something like below to make it clearer?

> 私が打った人は誰ですか。Who is the person I struck?
>
> 私を打った人は誰ですか。 Who struck me?

Comment: It's ambiguous and depends on context.

Comment: @Blavius: So I need to put either が or を before 打った?

Comment: It would help disambiguate, but I wouldn't say you *need* to as long as you can figure it out with surrounding text. Ambiguous sentences are very common in Japanese.

Comment: If you say うったひとは、だれですか。 out of nowhere in real life, I think it would sound more like 撃った人は誰ですか？ "Who shot the gun?" than "Who hit/struck me/someone?". And you'd probably say 私が撃ったのは誰ですか？　or 私は誰を撃ったんですか？　to say "Who did I shoot?"

Comment: Agreed. 打つ for "punch/beat someone" is an obsolete usage.

Comment: It also could be (この文書を)打った人は誰ですか？, couldn't it? ;)

Comment: @dinogeist あ～確かに・・・ It would no longer be ambiguous in that case (*この文書が打った・・・)

Comment: でもたぶん単独で使うなら、「打ち込んだ人」って言う気がしますね…

Comment: I initially read it as　「（ホームランを）打った人は誰ですか？」  Completely saw it as a conversation over baseball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence depends on context for the exact meaning. It can be either, since the grammatical role of the modified noun isn't explicitly given in Japanese. This includes things normally marked with が and を (subjects and objects), like in your example, but also to things marked with other particles, like で or に:

> 鉛筆で書いた -> 書いた鉛筆
>   私が店に入った -> 私が入った店

Just like in regular sentences, you can omit things from relativized clauses. This is another reason why relative clauses can be ambiguous (but of course, full sentences can be ambiguous for this same reason). You can often disambiguate by adding extra information, like you did in your last two sentences. However, don't feel like you have to make everything clear by putting in as much information as you can. Japanese tends to omit things that can be implied, and adding information already understood can actually be unnatural.

Another way to disambiguate is by making the relative verb passive:

> 撃たれた人 = person who was shot

I feel like this is less common for inanimate leading nouns, though.